# input text event is not triggered when updated using DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am having an issue trying to trigger the test() function when updating the input of type text "testName" using the DOM. Does it have something to do with the DOM itself? It works when I am directly clicking on the input of type text and modify it, but not when another JS function access it through DOM to modify it.

document.getElementById('testID').value = "test";

Thank you

Comment: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: Consider picking a [meaningful username](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). One advantage to this is others can use [at-replies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and you'll get a notification that someone has addressed you in a comment.

Comment: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete, concise and representative. Guess what the code in this question isn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to trigger the onchange event your code has to be like shown below

```
document.getElementById('testID').value = "test";
document.getElementById('testID').onchange();
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

unlike a text field, a text area has no value that gets populated. make a div  with id="testID" inside the text area and use that instead.

document.getElementById("testID").innerHTML="New text!";

if it is a text field, then your code should owrk

document.getElementById('testID').value = "something";

what are you using to trigger the event? onclick? onchange? what's it related to

Comment: I am sorry. I mean input text.

Comment: I am using onchange. Here is the input text: <input type="text" name='testName' id='testID' maxlength='255' class='textInput' onchange='test();'/>

Comment: and what are the functions you are using the command to set the value in? it could be something simple causing it to fail. copy the function test() and the other functions you are calling "test" under into your original post and we'll see what we can get done.

Comment: document.getElementById(testID).value = "test"; The value is changed when I do that, so it works. It is just that the onchange() event is not triggered.

Comment: If I type something in the input text directly, the test() function will be triggered, so the event works. But if I use the DOM, the content of the input text will change, but no event is being triggered.

Comment: might be silly, but onchange should be "onChange" (capital C)

Comment: I tried. It doesn't make any differences, plus I have other text input that are using onchange and it works perfectly. According to the w3c it is "onchange": http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp  . The only difference between the field from where the event is triggered and the one that is not working is that I am updating this one through the DOM.